# SOAP Faults - Integrating .NET WCF and Java WSImport

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, fault

I'm looking for help/advice on defining SOAP faults the correct way when creating a web service with .NET WCF and consuming it with JAX-WS (*wsimport*).

Let's assume my service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://sub.pub.com")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
    void OperationOne(int deviceId, int socket);

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
    void OperationTwo(int deviceId, int socket);
}
```

Somewhere in my service I'm doing the following...

```
throw new FaultException<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(...);
```

Generating the JAX-WS artifacts for the WSDL of my WCF service results in the following Java exceptions for *OperationOne* and *OperationTwo*:

- IServiceOperationOneArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionFaultFaultMessage
- IServiceOperationTwoArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionFaultFaultMessage

It works, but it is ugly and my code gets weird because there are two exceptions for the same thing (in this example: argument out of range).

- **Am I using the generic FaultException in a correct way?**
- **How do I consume such WSDL correctly with wsimport to generate just 1 exception?**